# Batch distance calculation with v.net.distance

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector, qgis-3, network-analysis

[image]

I have three shapefiles:

- one containing destinations
- the second containing postcodes
- the third containing the road network

I want to calculate the distance between the postcodes and destinations with the help of GRASS [v.net.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.distance.html) in QGISS 3.2 GUI.

I can easily calculate the distance with this tool between two points only but not between multiple feature(red dots show the destinations, the pink ones show the post codes).

Can anyone explain how to run the batch process for this?

Comment: So you want the distance from every postcode to every destination? How many of each type do you have?

Comment: 297 postcodes and 19 destinations

Comment: Have a look at the hub tools (`Distance to nearest hub (points)` and `Join by lines (hub lines)`). The documentation is a sketchy, but with some trial and error I think it will do what you want. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?highlight=hub#distance-to-nearest-hub-points

Comment: @csk I want the distance between the destination and it`s nearest postcodes.

Comment: Have you looked at v.net.allpairs (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.net.allpairs.html)? That will give you a matrix table showing the distance between every postcode and every destination. You could then simply trim out the combinations which have too long distances.

Comment: Are you strictly bound to use v.net.distance? There is a QGIS processing plugin that provides the necessary algorithms for you. I can describe it's usage in more detail if you are free to use QGIS python processing algorithms too.

Comment: PGRouting offers a solution too.

Comment: Could you please describe the PGRouting method? Is it an extension? Thanks?

Comment: I`m not bound to use v.net.distance. I just thought it was a straightforward way of calculating distance. I`m open to other solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I have 297 postcodes and 22 destinations

Comment: May be with the plugin OSM Tools (openrouteservice routing, isochrones and matrix calculations for QGIS)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution: I ran the v.net tool in GRASS GUI to connect the postcodes to the road network, then I ran the v.net.distance in QGISS GUI and it worked; I managed to find out which postcodes are the closest to which destination and the actual distance as well.